# Is there a way to determine what is the "top" section header of a UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, sections

Is there a way to determine what is the "top" section header of a UITableView?

For "top section header" I mean the section header that is sticky at the top of the UITableView bounds.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the section number using this:

```
NSUInteger sectionNumber = [tableView indexPathForCell: [[[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex: 0] section]];
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think this answer covers it best, although sticky things will happen during that transition period while two headers are visible together at the top...

Comment: I have used a similar method but, as Alex is pointing, it does not fit my needs, because I need to know what is the top visible group section header and this method fails where you have more than 1 section header visible at once.

Comment: The answer for NSUInteger sectionNumber = [tableView indexPathForCell: [[[tableView visibleCells] objectAtIndex: 0] section]]; is wrong.
It is NSInteger sectionNumber = [[tableView indexPathForCell:[[menu visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0]] section];

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the -(UIView) viewForHeaderInSection method. This will allow you to use your own UI view as the header for the table view section.

Comment: It's a UITableViewDelegate method.

Comment: viewForHeaderInSection isn't "sticky" :-)

Comment: It sticks over the current on screen section. Does as it does in contacts or music apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the TABLE header (and the TABLE footer) - not the SECTION header/footer, then you access it through `tableHeaderView` a property of the `UITableView`

```
tableHeaderView Returns an accessory view that is displayed above the table.

@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
```

If you want the SECTION header, then you need to create it by implementing the `UITableViewDelegate` method `-tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

```
tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: Asks the delegate for a view object to display in the header of the specified section of the table view.

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: I need a way to get the current NSUInteger of the group section header that is "sticky" at top.

Comment: Maybe a picture of the "sticky" part would help ? Not sure here cause the "Section Headers" are not sticky and slide in and out with their respective sections